# how to redirect to sub directory in htaccess without direct access to it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I already asked this question but no answers.

I develop new forum So I put some files like index, login, signup and etc... in sub directory called webroot and i want to redirect all requests to webroot without direct access to it for example:

localhost/myforum [root project files] should access with no problems but

localhost/myforum/webroot redirect to 404

myforum/.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

   # Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL is not directly related to physical file paths.
   # Also uncomment it if you are on 1&1 hosting
   #RewriteBase /

    # Comment the following line if you have not a .well-known directory in the root folder.
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

myforum/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `myforum/webroot/.htaccess` as this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # return 404 if accessed directly
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /webroot/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks very much but it helped me